# Redirect during loading the page in JSF2

Tags: jsf, redirect, richfaces

I use JSF2 and RichFaces and I want to change my view during loading other view, for example

```
<rich:panel rendered="#{MyMBean.necessaryToChangeView}" styleClass="passwordChangeReminder">... </rich:panel>
```

And methood in MyMbean:

```
public boolean isNecessaryToChangeView() {
    if (myRequirement...) {
          FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
          fc.getExternalContext().redirect(fc.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath() + "/pages/changePass.jsf");                

          return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

With this code I am getting

```
13:08:17,428 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Error Rendering View[/pages/bilboard/bilboardShow.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /pages/bilboard/bilboardShow.xhtml @30,108 rendered="#{MyMBean.necessaryToChangeView}": java.lang.IllegalStateException
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:419) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1773) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:851) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:439) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at my.web.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:73) [jleo-weblsp-client-web-mbean-2.00.00_beta.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at my.web.license.LicensesFilter.doFilter(LicensesFilter.java:77) [jleo-weblsp-client-web-mbean-2.00.00_beta.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at my.jleo.session.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:52) [jleo-weblsp-client-web-mbean-2.00.00_beta.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at my.jleo.login.SecurityCheckFilter.doFilter(SecurityCheckFilter.java:73) [jleo-weblsp-client-web-mbean-2.00.00_beta.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:91)
at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:72)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:499) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```

What is wrong with my code? Could anyone help me? I woud be very grateful ;)
    l

Comment: Just saying "IllegalStateException" is not enough, there is more information in there which you should post. I can only guess its 'response has already been committed'.

Comment: I edited my post to show more details

Comment: Just stop doing business/controller logic in getter methods.

Comment: I know about that but I am not my project supervisor...

Comment: Use the `preRenderView` event or if JSF 2.2 available the `viewAction` method.

Comment: While I'm not a fan of whatever it is you're trying to pull off in there (it's a massive code-smell), you might be able to get away with it by indicating `responseComplete` just after the redirect. But like XtremeBiker indicates, there are much, much better ways to do what you're trying to.